# SSRS - Internal server 500 error

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, microsoft-reporting

I am getting Http 500 error while rendering reportviewer. 
 the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
See the error below

```
http://localhost:59214/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=SessionKeepAlive&ControlID=837415b70bc74a908169e1274b125c25
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
(Internal Server Error)
```

I tried adding the following:

1. Added handler in `<webserver>`ie.

```html
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
```

3. Page directive added `ValidateRequest="false"`
4. AsyncRender ="False" in reportviewer.

Please help still i am getting the 500 error. I am using Vs2017 with Microsoft Report 12.0

### Update

See the Log file of SSRS server
[Log File - click to see][1]

[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cU9TzLdDPFiLzUbmyYR0FA9_p8CV_Joz/view?usp=sharing. My report is ***/Development/pd_Report_SalesPricingGrid***. Highlighted in the log bold and red.

Comment: I would suggest that with this and any other 500 response you take it to the error log as you are going to have more detailed information. Without that, it would be a guessing game. The SSRS logs are at <MSSQLS_INSTALL>\ReportServer\LogFiles. In that file you can search for the report you were calling when you received the 500 status response code and there should be more evidence of an issue. Post that, and maybe we can help.

Comment: Thanks... will look and let you know

Comment: @RossBush Update the question with log's link

Comment: You have one call to a production server where the report had not yet been deployed so there was a not found exception, however, everything else looks clean. You can safely rule out an error in the SSRS service. It is getting and processing the request.The next logical place to look would be in IIS. I would look for timeout settings ,authentication failures, protocol policy failures. You will find a record in the wp3 logs. If you can treace a bad request then I bet there will be more in the IIS log..